# another UIScrollView doesn't scroll

Tags: ios

First of the bat: I am aware of the fact, that thsi question was asked and answered several times here, but none of the answers worked for me so far.

So here's the deal I have a scrollView with multiple labels, images other stuff in my view. See the image. I have hooked it up to my code and believe, that I have also initialized it properly in my implementation. What am I doing wrong? iOS6 btw.

since I can't post images yet, I uploaded it here: http://oliverengelhardt.de/uploads/scrollViewOne.png

and the implementation code:

```
@synthesize scrollView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [scrollView setScrollEnabled:TRUE];
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 713)];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have made the content size of the scroll view in code the same size as its frame is in IB.  It will only scroll if the content is larger than the frame.

Comment: It's also larger than the screen is, so probably he wants to reduce the size of the scroll view and keep the content size as it is currently?

Comment: Thanks. Now it does work, kind of. I get the scroll bar to the side of the screen, but the content of the view doesn't move.

Comment: I also created a new project and tried to implement a scrollView there. Same problem. getting the scrolling bars but the content doesn't move.

Comment: Okay, tried another one in xCode 4.3.3 and it works there. May it be possible they changed smthng in xCode 4.5?